# JQuery autocomplete ui.item.value only returning one word - MVC3

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

:I have the following in one of my partial views:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ProductName").autocomplete({
            source: "Products",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#newInvoiceLineForm").load("/Invoices/Product?name=" + ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

And the autocomplete works fine and displays all the items returned but on select event I get a ui.item.value with just the first word of the two word item. For example I have "New Product" selected from the autocomplete and it results in the:

`/Invoices/Product?name=New` call.

Anyone had this situation before?

Thank you

---

This is the code that works with encodeURI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ProductName").autocomplete({
            source: "Products",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
              $("#newInvoiceLineForm").load(encodeURI("/Invoices/Product?name=" + ui.item.value));
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL encode your string. Spaces in their raw form aren't acceptable to querystrings.